# linking parse and stripe user

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

My app requires users to log in with Parse to make a purchase and uses parse cloud to process payments using Stripe.  Payment works fine.   I want to associate the card that just used to make the payment to the [PFUser currentUser] so I can load the cards for user to select next time.  How can I achieve that?  Is it possible to get the card information from the token?

P.S one user can have many card and one card can belong to many user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "card information" but it should be possible to achieve what you want. You'll want to first create a [Customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#customers) in Stripe to represent each user.  Each Stripe Customer has a [list of payment sources](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#customer_object-sources) associated with them, and you can read the `brand` and `last4` if you need to display a list of these to the user to select one.

Once you create a customer in Stripe, you can create any number of [Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges).

All of this can be done in a straightforward manner using the [intuitive Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/). You can also manage Customers and Charges via the Stripe dashboard.